# Movement Script In Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been trying to make a movement script for my player in a 2D game but without success. I do not know why it is not working.

The problem is that the player isn't moving. I have a `RigidBody` attached and gravity on. (Not sure if gravity makes such a difference but I just thought to mention it.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
   public Rigidbody rb;
   public float speed = 10;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    float mx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float mz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(mx, 0.0f, mz);
    Debug.Log(movement);
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

  }
}
```

Comment: As a curiosity, what does the Debug log show for ````movement```` when you adjust the axis? My hunch is that you are adding a force which is not enough to move the object. Checking your ````movement````, ````speed````, and ````Time.deltaTime```` variables for proper values would be my first thought.

Comment: My thoughts are the same as Kivak Wolf's. Keep in mind that `Time.deltaTime` is generally a really small number (1/60-ish). Since `speed` is 10 and the component values of `movement` only vary between -1 and 1, the final force you add is going to be quite small. Might not be enough to visually overcome the inertia of an object, let alone friction.

Comment: Thank you all for such quick responses. Awesome community. It started working when I changed the speed value.

Comment: The debug.log for the variable movement just logs the vector and I was checking if it was getting any input or not. It shows a vector with x,y,z in the console. The values can either be 0, 1 or -1. Thanks again for reading. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wanna make sure you are adding enough force to actually cause the player to move. Try increasing the force variable incrementally until you see a change. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Dont know why I didn't try that earlier. Hope you have an awesome day :)